# How to enable camera beep using ZXing.Net?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, zxing

I am working on **Xamarin** forms and I've implemented the **ZXing.Net** Bar code scanner.

Bar code is working fine but I want to customize the bar code reader in the following ways:

1. Customize the size of bar code scanner.
2. I want to enable the camera beep when scan the bar code.

Is this possible using the component?

Comment: Hello. I've edited your question's title to an actual question and I've reformatted the question slightly to make it clearer to people who might have the answers for you. Please see the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Comment: I too am trying to customize the size of the barcode scanner

Answer (score 1):

i assume that you initialized the  ZXing.Net Bar code scanner through a `ZXingScannerPage` like this

```
var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage(new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions { AutoRotate = false, })
            {
                DefaultOverlayTopText = "Align the barcode within the frame",
                DefaultOverlayBottomText = string.Empty
            };
```

But you can also use a `ZXingScannerView` like

```
var scanview = new ZXingScannerView();
        scanview.OnScanResult += result =>
        {
            scanview.IsScanning = false;
            //do something with the result
            //play sound
        };

        var stack = new StackLayout()
        {
            Children =
            {
                scanview
            }
        };
```

the  `ZXingScannerView` can be nested inside any other layout/view (Stack,Frame etc)

For **playing a sound** follow this guy [blogpost](http://chrfalch.blogspot.gr/2015/09/playing-sound-in-xamarinforms.html)

Comment: Thanks for replay. How we can change the resolution of Camera when using as barcode scanner?